# Too few arguments in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, arguments

All Excel-formulas with more than 1 argument, like the following, don't work.

```
=ROUNDDOWN(1.23, 0)
```

The Error-Message "you have entered too few arguements for this function." appears. Formulas with only one argument work.

It even appears when I create the formula with the formula-wizard.

Even uninstalling and reinstalling Excel doesn't fix the problem.

Anyone know a fix?

Comment: Where are you based? The argument delimiter is locale-dependent. You might need a `;` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel has problems with the list separators.

You can change the default list separator for Windows in:

Control Panel / Regional Settings / Additional Settings / List separators (This names might vary a little bit, I have only a German Windows).

Choose `;` as list separator.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting ";" instead of ",".

While coding in vba, "," is used but in excel itself use ";".

P.s.This is so at least in my country